# Firebase Firestore Returning Timestamp as Empty Object

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

```
firebase.firestore().collection('items')
```

Returns all strings as expected, but the created at timestamp is returned as an empty object {}

```
{"created_at":{},"name":"item one","description":"item one desc"}
```

How can I get it to provide the actual timestamp that appears in the db in the firebase console?

[image: As it appears in firebase console]

The result returned from the above collection is stored as `items` and is displayed in a table in vue js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Firestore Timestamp is an object, if you want to display it, you have to convert it into a js date object. You can [read more here in the public constructors section.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)

Example js:

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('items')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const data = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((item) => {
        const { created_at, ...rest } = item.data();

        data.push({
          created_at: new Date(created_at.seconds * 1000), // or you can use moment - moment.unix(created_at.seconds)
          ...rest,
        });
      });

      console.log(data); // [{"created_at": "2019-04-10T15:25:04.000Z", "name": "item one", "description": "item one desc"}]
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was looking for.